# PayPal plugin for PhoneGap in Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, paypal

Here is what I am trying to do. I want to use PayPal API to provide user with a payment option. I created PayPal developer account. I followed tutorial on this link: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin. I was able to make that sample code work. That is enough for my purpose. A screen appears and asks to choose Pay by Card or Pay by PayPal. I select Pay by Card. For the purpose of my project, I need to show a dummy payment's round trip.

But here is what happens: after selecting card, I enter a dummy test card number like 4111 1111 1111 1111 and then it asks me to enter a card number expiration date in future, so I enter 04/18 and just some number for CVV, assuming that it is all in Sandbox environment. But it fails.

What am I supposed to do? Something needs to be changed within the business account that I have been given? I have the clinet ID as well. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dummy credit card of 4 & 15 1's does not work consistently in the PayPal Sandbox due to overuse.  You'll need to use a card number that's listed on one of your other Sandbox accounts or you can use the card number generator located on the [PayPal Technical Support site](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/750/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made another account and used the cc number provided. I did not use the random cc number yet. Follow up questions: Could you explain how this process works? So in the sample code I put the facilitator account client ID and that's it. No matter which credit card number I use, meaning either the ones with buyer account or business account, txn still happens. There is random amount of $9999 showing up in one account and other amounts showing in other accounts? What is really happening? What is the use of the client ID? How does buying selling work here?

Comment: The client ID tells PayPal who the merchant/receiver of funds is for the transaction.  When you input and complete a payment using the facilitator account client ID, then the funds will be sent/received into that account.